# Gestures prediction issue in android

Tags: android, gestures

I am making an application in which user will be making gestures on screens and if the user has any contact number stored against that gesture , it will dial that number . now i am having an issue with recognition of gestures. the most primary issue i am facing is that if a user stores a number against a straight line , it will never be called because when ever user draw a straight line to call a contact it become translucent as it is not a valid gesture.

[translucent image http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/images/gestures_003.png](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/images/gestures_003.png)

Can any one help me with this so i can recognize this gesture as well or is there any way i can stop my user from making such gesture?
And also can any one tell me how to improve recognition of gestures?

Comment: sorry, can't help, :) but couldn't hold myself: to stop your user from making such gesture, you can spit cold water in his face or sound a loud horn when he does it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, why would you want to do this? You know very well that the straight line gesture is used to scroll down. This is probably by design.

---

[image]